# code navigation within python module not possible in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

first of all, this is my workspace structure:

```
workspace_root
├── ...
├── libs
│   └── module_name
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── module_name
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── caller_with_main_calls_service.py
│       │   ├── independent.py
│       │   └── service_calls_indendent.py
│       └── setup.py
├── ...
```

my issue?

In VSCode, I can't navigate within a module's elements definition.
That includes jumping from the `import` statement straight to the definition of it.
I even couldn't start or debug the python main within `caller_with_main_calls_service.py`, because it said `module not found`.
When installing the module via pip, it works. 
However, that's not desired during development...

What I tried so far:

- tried `.env` approach and set `PYTHONPATH` to my interpreter + `${workspaceRoot}+"/libs/module_name/module_name"`
- set the workspace settings / settings.json like this:

```
{
   "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
   "python.linting.enabled": true,
   "python.pythonPath": "/path/to/conda_env/python",
   "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
       "${workspaceRoot}/libs/module_name/module_name"
   ],
   "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

- before starting VSCode, I exported the `$PYTHONPATH` env var in the same manner as in 1) to include the lib path

What does the python files from the module look like:

```
# example: caller_with_main_calls_service.py
from module_name import service_calls_indendent as sci
```

Not sure, if that's relevant, but I am working with WSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, it's not enough to put `from . import service_calls_independent` aka relative imports.

Additionally, the `launch.json` needs to be adapted:

```
    {
      "name": "Python: Module Runner",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "module": "libs.module_name.caller_with_main_calls_service",
      "args": [
            1,
            2,
            3
      ],
      "env": {
        "FOO": "BAR"
      }
    }
```

The important part is the `module`, where you specify the file with the main inside - without any file extension.

Answer (score 1):

[This is assuming you're using Python 3]

Navigation isn't working because the Python extension is looking in your workspace directory and any place specified in `PYTHONPATH`. So in this instance your import doesn't make sense to the extension because there is no module or package named `module_name` under `workspace_root` or `workspace_root/libs`. And because you specified an absolute import Python is only looking for module or packages with the name specified and not looking next to where you did the import.

I'm not quite sure what code/directory structure you're after, but either change your import to `from . import service_calls_indendent` or open `workspace_root/libs/module_name` as your workspace instead.

Comment: already tried your suggestion before.
with that, the navigations within vscode is working.
however if I want to run `caller_with_main_calls_service.py`, which imports the own libraries, I get the following error:
```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
attempted relative import with no known parent package
  File "/home/mf/code/caller_with_main_calls_service", line 2, in <module>
    from . import log_step_orchestrator as lso
```

Comment: @mchlfchr how are you executing it?

Comment: Assuming that you mean by "it" the application, I'm loading the whole root project into VSCode.
I just used the default lauch configuration on the file `caller_with_main_calls_service.py`.
As you may have seen, I solved it (see within my answer).

Answer (score -1):

Please install below extensions it will autmatically configure vscode and you can easily find the defincations, source and also it will suggest the optimised way to code

[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njpwerner.autodocstring](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=trixnz.go-to-method)

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=trixnz.go-to-method

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Comment: I have the python extension installed and not sure why I need your other extensions for that...
i am basically able to debug and run python, so that isn't really related to the question.